# The without a contextual type error for .default member of alert button

Tags: swift, swiftui

This example code show a button represent a alert when you click it.

```
struct LoginView: View {
    ...
    @State private var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ...

                Button("Login") {
                    self.showAlert = true
                }
                .alert(isPresented: self.$showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Login error"), message: Text("detail message"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))  // this line report a error
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Login View")
        }
    }
}
```

But Xcode report a `Reference to member 'default' cannot be resolved without a contextual type` error message when I compile this code. How should I fix this code?

Comment: The code you provided built without errors. Xcode 11.2.1, iOS 13.2.2.

Comment: This code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The project with presented code builds fine in `iOS Simulator` and `iOS device`, without any errors. `Canvas Simulator` also works fine (I used Xcode 11.2.1 and iOS 13.2.2).

[image]

Try to delete all the compiled projects in your folder `DerivedData`.

In Finder press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> and go to:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

After cleaning the content of this folder, build your project again, it must work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found out experimentally that Xcode provide this stupid behavior because of compilation problem in another path of code (it shows compilation error you have but not in place which is a source of this error).

My solution is next:

1) **Comment all content inside**

```
public var body: some View {
   . . . . . 
}
```

2) **Build project with success**

3) **Uncomment view by view**. Successful build after every uncommenting will help you to find a real wrong place

For example, I had a problem with ***sendRequest*** function

```
Button(
        action: {

            self.sendRequest(requestUrl: self.requestUrl!, requestData: self.requestData!, requestMethod: RequestMethod.GET, handler: { rd, sa, am in
                                        self.responseData = rd
                                        self.showingAlert = sa ?? false
                                        self.alertMessage = am
                                    })

        },
        label: { Text("Get Data") }
       )
       .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
           Alert(title: Text("Important!"), message: Text("\(alertMessage!)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
       }
       .buttonStyle()
```

and Xcode showed a "The without a contextual type error for .default member of alert button" error on "Alert..." line

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message because the brackets were not correctly paired. Your code works, these versions also work:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
    Alert(title: Text("Title"),
          message: Text("An alert"),
          primaryButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {
          }),
          secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel"), action: {
          })
    )
}
```

or this:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
    Alert(title: Text("Title"),
          message: Text("An alert"),
          primaryButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
          },
          secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel"))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error which I faced while creating my cocoa pod:

```
error: reference to member 'originalImage' cannot be resolved without a contextual type
```

**Solution:**

For my case, I have updated my own cocoa pod code features that Apple delivered from Swift 5.0 only. But I have mentioned my Swift version 4.0. I have changed the Swift version to `Swift 5.0` in the `podspec` file. It's charmingly works fine for me.

> *spec.swift_versions = "4.0"* → **spec.swift_versions = "5.0"**